# Pulling Data across Sheets within a Google Sheets Workbook

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets within the same google sheets workbook. first sheet name is "POP" while the second sheet name is "PracticeTracker". POP sheet has row 1 as header row. starting from A2, column A contains student names (sometimes with duplicates). I want to pull these names (unique names only) into PracticeTracker sheet column B (starting at B6) using a formula but in such a way that each student name would appear  in alternate cells. means name of first student should appear in B6 and next student name should appear in B8 and so on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cbGZymK7z-EBP3IAhB2GIEmi84bLQfDE84mYGxTLHm4/edit#gid=1744051844

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(POP!A2:A,1)),
       tocol({Σ,wrapcols(,counta(Σ),)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help and support. Best solution.